# p5.js with angularjs - help creating a model for an object I'd like to draw

Tags: angularjs, p5.js, matter.js

I’d like to create a model for the objects I’m drawing but I’m struggling with how to do that in Angular. I know p5 methods aren’t recognized outside of specific functions but that seems to be what I need to do here?

I’m attempting to follow along with The Coding Train [here](https://youtu.be/urR596FsU68?t=960) where he does something similar.

I've tried putting the code into another draw() method inside of the box model but I don't believe that's the correct thing to do.

```
import * as Matter from 'matter-js';
import * as p5 from 'p5';

export class Box {

 ...

  show() {

       let pos = this.body.position;
       let angle = this.body.angle;

       p5.push();
       p5.translate(pos.x, pos.y);
       p5.rect(0,0, this.w, this.h);
       p5.pop();

 ...
```

I'd like to be able to export that into a component, instantiate a new box, and call .show() on it within my instanced draw() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems instead of importing p5 into my Box model I can pass my instance of p5 into the show method as such.

From my component...

```
const sketch = (s) => {

...

s.draw = () => {
   s.background(51);
   // s.rect(box1.position.x, box1.position.y, 80, 80);
   box1.show(s)
 };

...
```

And updated Box model show() method

```
...

show(p5) {
   let pos = this.body.position;
   let angle = this.body.angle;

   p5.push();
   p5.translate(pos.x, pos.y);
   p5.rect(0,0, this.w, this.h);
   p5.pop();

...
```